# Deploying app with socket.io to Heroku problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy my game on heroku.
The problem is that everything works very well on localhost, but after deploying, nothing works.
I've already reread all the similar questions here, and tried everything.
At the moment, I have this configuration.

**Server.js**

```
 const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const useSocket = require("socket.io");
const RpslsLogic = require('./GameLogic/rspls.js')

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "src")))

const io = useSocket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true,
        transports: ['websocket']
    }
})


io.on('connection', socket => {
      socket.emit('connection')
    })

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server started on port 5000..."));
```

**app.js**

```
 export const socket = io()

function App() {
    const [socketId, setSocketId] = useState('')
    socket.on('connection', () => {
        setSocketId(socket.id)

    })
```

**Package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node src/server.js"
```

I have already tried inserting the address of the application on heroku in the socket on the client, it did not work.

As a result, I can't get socket.id and connections

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Mmx.png)

[Heroku Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2gPd.png)

Comment: Is your server not even starting? Does this work console.log("Server started on port 5000..."));

Comment: @Tushar Shahi
And where should it appear? I made a screenshot on the site in the logs. Doesn't the 200 answer mean that the server is definitely working?